# How to Read a text file add line to List<> in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, streamreader

I have this code for get a column in a text file (cvs) that I only need 2 first columns

```
List<string> SubStations = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader leer = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default, true))
{

    string line;
    while ((line = leer.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        SubStations.Add(line);
    }
}

foreach (var item in SubStations)
{
    string[] StationDivision = item.Split(',');
    Console.WriteLine("Station {0}, Substation {1}",
        StationDivision[0].ToString(), 
        StationDivision[1].ToString());
}
```

I would like to know, if I can put the code surrounded by the foreach in the while iterator and don't use a list<>, and make it with linq?

Comment: Use a library such as `CsvHelper` to parse the csv and extract the data you want instead.

Comment: CSV has parsing rules, so Split() may not be a good choice. It's not terribly challenging to implement, but if the object is to read the file rather than to learn to write simple parsers, use a library as Jeff suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the entire file using `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`, which will return a `List<string>`. Then you can simply do a `Select` on it, split the cols and return the resulting array.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file").Select(x => x.Split(',') );

foreach (var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine($"Station {line[0]}, Substation {line[1]}");
```

Comment: with the code that supply @Abolfazl I I modified it like this:      File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\subestaciones.txt").Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine("Station {0}, Substation {1}",
                      f[0].ToString(),
                      f[1].ToString()));

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    line.Split(',').Select(x => 
        $"Station {x[0]}, Substation {x[1]}")
    );
```

But as noted, you should use a Csv parser library instead.

Comment: the line is a list<>? or what kind of type is line? (array)?, I don´t need library for a simple read csv file.

Comment: @ger This code is meant to be inside your `while` loop, replacing `SubStations.Add(line);`,  so it's the `line` string you have defined

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of `foreach`,Why you don't use following code?

```
SubStations.Select(x=>x.Split(',')).ToList().ForEach(f=>Console.WriteLine("Station {0}, Substation {1}",
        f[0].ToString(), 
        f[1].ToString()))
```

Comment: but where is the iterator for readAllLines? but your code was helpful!! to make a code in one line with the help of @pascx64      File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\subestaciones.txt").Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine("Station {0}, Substation {1}",
                      f[0].ToString(),
                      f[1].ToString()));